# How to transform and transpose data (non-numeric) in SQL query

Tags: sql

Good day

Appreciate if someone know how to how to transform and transpose data (non-numeric) in SQL query table

For example (from the transform the multiple identical customer_id into unique row with transpose the value

[image: Example of table transform enquiry]

Warmest regards

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select customer_id,
       max(case when question = 'loyalty' then answer end) as loyalty,
       max(case when question = 'satisfaction' then answer end) as satisfaction
from t
group by customer_id;
```

Comment: Dear  Gordon Linoff , noted with great thanks!